# Previously installed 12.04 alongside Windows, would like to install over Windows

Tags: installation, windows

About 8 months ago I installed 12.04LTS via wubi, then chose to fully install and I selected for it to install alongside windows

Fast forward to today, and I really hate Windows 8 (it previously had 7 installed) and I want to fully install Ubuntu over windows.

I've tried to use wubi again and unetbootin and all of that, to no avail. I just want the most blunt, fast, and effective way to install only Ubuntu and get rid of Windows forever

Cheers,

Austin

Answer (score 0):

I tried [pendrivelinux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/) yesterday and it worked like a charm. Supposing you want to install Ubuntu 12.04 i386 from an USB drive

Comment: Tried to download Universal USB Installer, gives me this error:


Archive:  /home/ametheral/Downloads/Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.5.2 (1).exe
[/home/ametheral/Downloads/Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.5.2 (1).exe]
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
zipinfo:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of /home/ametheral/Downloads/Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.5.2 (1).exe or

Comment: /home/ametheral/Downloads/Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.5.2 (1).exe.zip, and cannot find /home/ametheral/Downloads/Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.5.2 (1).exe.ZIP, period.

Comment: This is the link: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/downloads/Universal-USB-Installer/Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.5.2.exe

Comment: Ah I'm using ubuntu right now. I will switch to windows, install, and see how it goes and let you know after. Cheers

Comment: Ok, it worked but I was expecting to see something like this http://assets.ubuntu.com/sites/ubuntu/672/u/img/download/screenshot-desktop-trail-2.png there, but there isn't. Remember I want to install Ubuntu over windows and have only ubuntu running, Thanks!